# Can I use Google Analytics on AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, google-analytics, aws-lambda

I am trying to embed the [google analytics initialization call](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) into an AWS Lambda function. I'm getting the exception `ReferenceError: window is not defined` which makes sense seeing as there isn't a browser window. Is there a way to initialize the script so I can make `ga()` calls in AWS Lambda?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Consolidate my tracking into google analytics. And tracking dynamic things that coexist with other things in AWS.

Comment: Effectively, anything can be recorded as a tracked event and I can bring together things from multiple AWS services as part of my analytics tracking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong SDK. That initialisation is for the web app, which is meant to run on the front-end with access to `window`. Instead, use the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

Comment: Ah, I think you're right. I didn't find this in my searches. Looks promising!